# Searching Multi-Dimensional Array

Tags: c++

I've created a multi-dimensional array in C++, but it doesn't return anything when I search it.  Just wondering if I messed something up in the code? Full disclosure:  This was originally a class assignment, but I turned it in 2 weeks ago.  I'm asking for clarification for future programs.

I've put the main body (minus some of the list since it's 1000 entries) below

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    std::string name;
    std::string age;


    //declare 1000*2 Array     
    std::string array[1000][2] = 
   {
      { "Karen Rose","25"       },
{   "Cora Faison","11"      },
{   "Donna Jones","49"      },
{   "Robert Lowe","31"      },
{   "Patricia Johnston","17"    },
{   "Maryanne Hicks","40"       },
{   "James Mcmurray","53"       },

};

    cout << "Enter a name to search for " << endl;
    cin >> name;

    for(int i = 0; i > 1000; i++)
    {
        if(name == array[i][0])
        {
            age = array[i][1];
            cout << name << "'s age is" << age << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "we found nothing" << endl;
    }

}

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: What exactly went wrong? Did you have error messages?

Comment: Please fix the indentation. TIA.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: I> 1000 makesyour loop empty.

Comment: It starts to run and asks me to search for a name, but when I enter one it freezes up.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.  I'll rerun it with the for loop properly counting up.

Comment: Voting to close for typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for(int i = 0; i > 1000; i++)` should be `for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)`. The way you wrote it your `for` loop will never be executed.

Answer (score 2):

Beyond having your loop test backward, using `cin >> name` will only get the first name.  You test first and last.  Thus your tests will never succeed.

Use `std::getline`.

Doing a modicum of debugging work would have turned up both errors.

Answer (score 0):

I > 1000 makes your loop empty. < is the ooerator you want.

But anyway why 1000 and not 7?

Comment: Like I said, it was originally a class project (long since turned in).  I'm just playing around with it because I wanted to know why it wasn't working.